# Scaling vector by other vector to match its projection

Tags: vectors

I have 2 vectors a and b. They both are 3D.

I would like to scale vector b, so that its projection would be the same length as vector b.

I attached a sketch below. How much should I scale vector b so that its projection would be the same length as a

[Vector Projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sjS4.png)

Comment: Do you mean that the projection should be the same length as $|\vec a|$?

Comment: Yes the projection of B should be vector a.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{\vec a\cdot \vec b}{|\vec a||\vec b|}$$

Suppose you scale $\vec b$ such that the new vetcor is $k\vec b$, what is $\cos(\alpha)k|\vec b|$ by looking at the figure?

Comment: Hmm, first step is to get cos between two vectors. And then scale the vector B by that cos?

Answer (score 0):

The length of the projection of $\vec b$ onto $\vec a$ is, as I’m sure you already know, equal to ${\vec a\cdot\vec b \over \|\vec a\|}$. You’re looking for a scalar $\lambda$ such that $${\vec a\cdot(\lambda\vec b) \over \|\vec a\|} = \lambda {\vec a\cdot\vec b \over \|\vec a\|} = \|\vec a\|.$$ Solve this equation for $\lambda$.